# In App Purchase for online course App - iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, flutter-in-app-purchase

Our app is an online education app, which provides online courses inside the app. Students can purchase the course they want inside the app via in_app_webview feature,

For android, there's no problem.
For iOS, Apple wants us to in App Purchase, for that they levy 30%, which we don't want to pay...

Is anyone facing the same problem?...

I tried n number of appeal, but they want us to integrate IAP

Comment: Apple's [guidelines are clear](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase). For content delivered in the app you must use IAP. You cannot use other purchase methods. Until you reach US$1,000,000 revenue per year, the commission is 15%.  You should also be [using Play Store in app purchases on Android](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10281818?hl=en), but the Play Store review is less thorough so they don't always pick these things up.

Comment: but they approved our app today.. after this reply
Thank you for contacting the App Review Board. We received your appeal for your app, ***My App Name***, and it is currently being evaluated.

If the App Review Board determines that the original rejection feedback was valid, we will inform you directly via App Store Connect. If we identify additional issues as we consider your appeal, we will let you know.

If the App Review Board determines that the original rejection feedback was not accurate and there are no additional issues, your app will be approved.